# Corelating between the concept of Universal Hashing wrt Algorithms (hash-table use) & the use of Universal Hashing in a one-time MAC

Tags: hash, mac, universal-hash, carter-wegman

Trying to understand the concept of a Universal Hashing function.

From Introduction of Algorithms by Cormen, Rivest et al

> We now define the hash function $h_ab$ for any $a \in Z^*_p$ and any $b \in Z_p$ using a linear transformation followed by reductions modulo $p$ and then modulo $m$:

> $h_{ab}(d) = ((ad + b) \mod p) \mod m)$

I understand the above from an algorithmic point of view for use in a hash-table. i.e. if you have some data, which you need to hash to get a bucket/index number, you pick a random a & b from the sets & evaluate the function $h_ab$ at d. There is only a **single input** to the function once you picked the a & b.

But instead if we are using for a getting a hash in cryptography (for e.g. for using in a one-time MAC like Carter-Wegman MAC), then we now have **2 inputs** - a key (a cryptographic key rather than a key to be hashed for a hash table) & also the message to hashed. So how does it work here? For simplicity, if I assume a single block of message, then how do I use this universal function to evaluate the hash?

TL;DR - a Universal Hash function has only one input when used with Hash Tables, but 2 inputs when used in Cryptography for a one-time-MAC. What's the relation between these 2 kinds of hash functions. All places (Textbooks, Wikipedia etc) I look at, universal hashing is defined in terms of a single input functions, so how does it differ for functions taking 2 inputs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For simplicity, if I assume a single block of message, then how do I use this universal function to evaluate the hash?

We shift some parameters from being part of the concrete function instance into the key.

For your example of $h_{ab}(d)=ad+b\mod p\mod m$ the following mapping is usual:

- $d$ is the input to be hashed
- $a$ is the secret key of the instantiation, reusable across multiple invocations
- $b$ is the whitening value, it must be freshly random and hidden from adversaries for each invocation
- $p,m$ are system parameters that depend on in which field you want to work and into which you have to encode your result, e.g. you could pick $p$ to be a relatively large prime and $m=2^k$ for some $k$.

Alternatively, if you insist on having only two non-parameter inputs, you can also force $a$ to have the same usage constraints as $b$ and declare them both "the key".

Comment: So in your case that a is fixed & b is the randomly chosen value, then picking from a family of hash functions essentially means choosing a random b for each invocation? Am I right? The concept of "picking from a family of functions" is a little abstract & confusing for me, hence clarifying this.

Comment: @user93353 a is randomly chosen once and kept a fixed secret (usually) and b is freshly random for each hashing you perform (and also kept secret there). So in a sense you first pick a family (set) of hash functions by picking the parameters m,p, then pick a family from that family by picking a and then you finally pick the actual function by picking b.

Comment: @SEJPM  Do you know of an example of what you have just described, given in full detail for a layman?  On the internet?  In a book?

Comment: @Patriot The best reference I have off-hand is probably https://cryptobook.us 's section 7.4-7.6. Though its target audience is usually people wanting to get into academic crypto.

Comment: @SEJPM  Thank you very much!  I'll dig through it.